# How can my C# app display the PublishUrl from the VisualStudio publishing system from within the app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to include the PublishUrl value in a help menu in my C# app.  Mostly to aid in debugging if automatic updating is not working.  If the user cannot access the referenced network location, that explains why the update is not working and is a step forward for the user to figure out what is wrong.  I'm seeing the problem mostly from new users not having sufficient privileges on the network so the problem is not something the app can correct.

I'm just looking to do something simple like

```
String info = "Publish URL is " + PublishUrl;
DiaglogResult res = MessageBox.Show( info, "Help", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

This question is somewhat specific to Visual Studio (Community 2022 64-bit in my case) because PublishUrl is define in the project's .csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrl>\\server\Share\xxx\yyy\AppName\</PublishUrl>
```

The problem is that PublishUrl in the above code snippet is undefined and I'm not sure how to find the correct path to get to it.

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: I'm so new to C# I'm actually not certain of the difference or the answer; however, I believe it's .NET Framework

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create the profile, make sure that it is copied to the output folder by changing the properties in visual studio.  Just thrown this together, but I am sure you can do better, it will work though.

Put this is your own class.

```
 public string GetPublishPath()
    {
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create($"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}\\Properties\\PublishProfiles\\FolderProfile.pubxml"))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType.ToString() != "Whitespace" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    var el = XNode.ReadFrom(reader) as XElement;

                    var publishDir = el.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "PublishDir").Value;

                    return publishDir;
                }
            }

        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Good luck!